# can I add a function to this jquery?

Tags: jquery

Probably a simple one to do but I cannot get it working, I want to add a simple fade in to the appearing text that is triggered by this jquery (with great help from mr. Rao):

```
$('.col').on('mouseover',function()
{
$('.grafischewerktekst').text($(this).attr('data-desc'))
});
```

I guess I need something like this :

```
function(){
$(this).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

But how and where it will fit correctly I have not figured out yet?

Comment: `$('.grafischewerktekst').text($(this).attr('data-desc')).fadeOut('slow')`

Comment: Thank you for the nswer - Mr Rao helped me with the code after me struggling - one question: where exactly does it fit in the code I already have?

Comment: This worked for a one time-only fade out:   $('.col').on('mouseover',function()
{
    $('.grafischewerktekst').text($(this).attr('data-desc'))
 $('.grafischewerktekst').text($(this).attr('data-desc')).fadeOut('slow')
}); But changing the Out to In does not work? Mouseout would be a nice extra

Comment: Okay - I see it needs to come directly after what I allready have. The fadeOut works only once than everything stops dead. Changing Out to In - which is the desired effect - does not do anything. So I must be doing something wrong but what? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4z3k55eo/3/)

If following HTML and CSS given, you can change jQuery code as follows.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="col" data-desc="DESCRIPTION">LINK</a>

<div class="grafischewerktekst">SOME DIV</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grafischewerktekst
{
    display:none
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.col').on('mouseover',function()
{
   $('.grafischewerktekst').text($(this).attr('data-desc')).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the code Hemal - however it works only once: there are 4 images with 4 different texts that are displayed when hovering that particular image. On mouse out the text that was triggered last remains visible - could that be the problem, maybe when the text is hidden on mouse out the fade in effect will be triggered with each next hover over action?